# How to upload file to the server

Tags: c#

Help please.
There is some site and i have to upload there some amount of files.
I don't have access to source files of that site. This site exists.
There is form that gets file and button that sends it.
I don't know how to make post request to upload file to the form.
I used restsharp to do it, but file doesn't send. I need any solution that really sends file. It doesn't matter with restsharp or not. Next code do something but doesn't send file, it takes some time but there is no result.

C# code:

```
var client = new RestClient(tempUrl);
client.CookieContainer = cookie;

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("name", "fileUpload[uploadFile]");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=---WebKitFormBoundary" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x"));
                            request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary"+ DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x") + ", ------WebKitFormBoundary" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x") + "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\"; filename=\"" + file + "\"\r\nContent-Type: false\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x"), ParameterType.RequestBody);

request.AddFile("filename", File.ReadAllBytes(file), getOnlyName(file));

request.AddParameter("boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x") + "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"yt0\"" + "Загрузить" + ", ------WebKitFormBoundary" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x"), ParameterType.RequestBody);

RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
string rep1 = response.ToString();
```

Html code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="file-upload-importWln-form" action="/backend/units/importWln/id/43656" method="post">  

    <div class="row">  
        <label for="fileUpload_uploadFile">Загрузить файл</label>  
        <input id="ytfileUpload_uploadFile" type="hidden" value="" name="fileUpload[uploadFile]">  
        <input name="fileUpload[uploadFile]" id="fileUpload_uploadFile" type="file">            
    </div>  

    <div class="row buttons">
        <input class="button" type="submit" name="yt0" value="Загрузить">   
    </div>

</form>
```

Also there are params that i think must be in the request, but i don't know how to put them:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarySM5d7XYS2AzlAVLv  
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileUpload[uploadFile]"  


------WebKitFormBoundarySM5d7XYS2AzlAVLv  
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileUpload[uploadFile]"; filename=""  
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundarySM5d7XYS2AzlAVLv  
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="yt0"  

Загрузить  
------WebKitFormBoundarySM5d7XYS2AzlAVLv--
```

Comment: Many hits if you google for *c# multipart/form-data upload*.  Whatever you do don't keep on rebuilding the boundary string with  DateTime.Now.Ticks as it needs to be constant.

Comment: @Alex K If i make boundary constant, the file wii be sent?